# SQL básico (Join e Where)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Boa noite,

Estou tentando resolver um problema que é o seguinte:

Tabelas:

```
editoras (cod int primary key, nome varchar (50));

autores (cod int primary key, nome varchar (50));

livros (isbn char (13), titulo varchar (50), ano_publicacao int,
qtd_estoque int, valor decimal (10,2), id_editora int);
id_editora referencia Editoras

livros_autores (isbn char (13), id_autor int)
isbn referencia Livros
id_autor referencia Autores
```

[image: Tabela povoada]

A questão pede para eu obter o(s) nome(s) do(s) autor(es) que publicaram o livro mais barato. Daí, eu coloquei o seguinte

```
select nome from Autores
Inner Join Livros_autores as La 
On  La.id_autor= Autores.cod
Inner Join Livros as Liv 
On La.isbn = Liv.isbn
where valor = (select min(valor) from Livros)
```

Mas a coluna nome não é mostrada :(
O que acham que tem de errado?

Comment: O valor não é mostrado porque não aparece na lista de campos do select.

Comment: o join não deveria ser por isbn? `inner join livros_autores on livros.isbn = livros_autores.isbn`? esses campos ai da sua query não parecem existir domo o @anonimo mencionou

Comment: Eu acabei errando na pergunta, troquei id por cod, pois na minha query dizia que id era palavra reservada (ela ficou destacada). 
Modifiquei o inner e continua não aparecendo nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter o ivro mais barato de cada autor faça:

```
SELECT autores.nome, livros.isbn, MIN(livros.valor) 
FROM autores    INNER JOIN livros_autores ON (autores.cod = livros_autores.id_autor)
                    INNER JOIN livros ON (livros_autores.isbn = livros.isbn)
GROUP BY autores.nome, livros.isbn;
```

Se desejar apenas o mais barato acrescente:

```
ORDER BY 3 ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu select não está requisitando o campo `valor`, por isso só mostra o nome:

> select nome from Autores 
>   Inner Join Livros_autores as La 
>   On  La.id_autor= Autores.cod
>   Inner Join Livros as Liv 
>   On La.isbn = Liv.isbn
>   where valor = (select min(valor) from Livros)

Adicione o campo no select:

```
select nome, liv.valor (...)
```

---

**EDIT**

Como citado nos comentários, o livro mais barato não possui relacionamento correspondente na tabela `livros_autores`, fazendo com que a condição do `inner join` não seja atendida.

Se desejar exibir o livro mais barato QUE tenha autor, altera a condição do subselect. Mas eu **não recomendo** isso. 
Acredito que o ideal seja que cada livro tenha obrigatoriamente um autor válido, já que não existe livro sem autor.

Comment: Ah não, é que eu esqueci de informar... la no query, eu acabei colocando cod no lugar de id, pois id estava como palavra reservada.

Comment: id não é palavra reservada do PostgreSQL como você pode verificar na documentação: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: De qualquer forma, agora que entendi o problema. Editei a resposta, @MadsonRocha

Comment: Ela ficou destacada kkkkk, por isso achei que fosse reservada, perdão.

Comment: Continua não aparecendo, Ronaldo. Pelo que percebo o erro é no where, pois quando testo as outras linhas de código, aparece a seguinte tabela:

Nome ------- Valor
João ------- 60.00
José ------- 80.00
Lúcia ------- 90.00
Maria ------- 70.00
João ------- 90.00
Carlos ------- 80.00
José ------- 50.00

Comment: Na verdade, ele não mostra nada, nem nome nem valor. Apenas mostra as colunas.

Comment: Se não mostra nada, edite a pergunta e diga que não retorna nenhum registro, porque falar que "o campo X não é msotrado" dá a entender que só o campo não é exibido. (e siga isso para as próximas perguntas que fizer)

Comment: Confira se o livro de menor valor tem uma ligação correspondente na tabela `Livros_autores`, e se esta tem um correspondente na `livros`

Comment: Perdão pelo erro. Tem ligação. O autor que deveria aparecer é o José, todos os dados da tabela batem para que ele seja mostrado na tela.

Comment: Pelos dados que você apresentou em sua questão o menor valor 40,00 do livro 863 e o livro 863 não aparece na tabela livros_autores, portanto não existe registro em sua junção que atenda ao critério. José aparece como autor dos livros 425 e 213 com valores 80,00 e 50,00.

Comment: Exatamente, isso faz com que o José tenha o livro mais barato, já que o dono do livro de isbn 863 não tem na tabela livros_autores.

Comment: Estou usando o Inner Join para comparar os valores das tabelas Autores, Livros_Autores e Livros e o único dado que bate é o José.

Comment: @MadsonRocha Na verdade não. O livro mais barato continua sendo o de 40$. Lembre que seu subselect é `(select min(valor) from livros)`, ele considera apenas o valor, não os relacionamentos.

Comment: Então como faço para mostrar o resultado dos relacionamentos? Levando em consideração o valor mais barato.

Comment: Adicionando os `inner join` no subselect como está no select

Comment: Creio que você não entendeu corretamente como funciona o INNER JOIN e aonde se aplica a cláusula WHERE.  Tente utilizar a cláusula GROUP BY com a função de agregação MIN ao resultado de suas junções.

Comment: Eu vou estudar direitinho e corrigir os erros nas próximas questões. Agradeço a disposição e paciência para me ajudar <3.